# mysql replication using galera

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I want to learn how to use Galera cluster replication (MariaDB).

1. Can anyone give an advice that I can start from specific point?
2. Is it compatible with vsphere?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

Multiply Things you must know before using Galera Cluster.

1. Galera Cluster is not for scale write
2. Galera Cluster is not load balancer. It must integrate with HA Tools for this option
3. It's [virtually synchronized](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/architecture.html) Multi-master Replication
4. You need minimum of 3 nodes/servers(or 2 nodes and 1 abrirator)  to avoid split/brain.
5. You can't use MyISAM all of tables must be InnoDB.

So if you want to use Galera Cluster I thinks [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04-servers) article is good for start.

Comment: You can write to every node; what do you mean by your point #1?

Comment: @RickJames I mean it is not suitible tool for concurrent writing on multiply Masters because it can lead to deadlock.

Comment: Any configuration can lead to deadlocks.  Arguably Galera can get more deadlocks because of the delay in `COMMIT` while it checks with the other nodes.  Some applications never have deadlocks because they are never hitting the same rows.

Comment: one last thing , can i use it to do the replication across tow datacenters?

Comment: @YaserJawi Yes you can do it. Even you can design Geo-Distributed Database Clusters. Read this article for more information http://galeracluster.com/2015/07/geo-distributed-database-clusters-with-galera/: